# Why is a ObjC 'NSString * _Nullable' is transformed to a 'String!' property in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, bridging-header

In my Objective C code I have the property:
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * _Nullable myNullableString;`

I wanna use it in my Swift code but in this case, Xcode / Sourcekit thinks that `myNullableString` has not the type `String?` but has the type `String!`.

Due to this fact a guarded unwrapping the property is incorrect but also a forced use is incorrect and will lead to a crash of Xcode / SourceKit or to an segfault if I wanna build it.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, _Nullable works as intended for me. Can you provide a minimal self-contained example?

Comment: Command-Shift K, then build again might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying it. Not at the moment. The source is from an in-house framework. Do you get a String? property if you use _Nullable?

Comment: @gnasher729 I cleaned the project, the build folder and the deviated data folder. But I get still this kind of weirdness.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * _Nullable myNullableString;` is imported as `public var myNullableString: String? { get }`. – Try it in a new project with a small sample class. Then see if there are differences to your real project.

Comment: It looks like Martin is right...if it still doesn't work, it could be an Xcode version thing. Buggiest IDE I've ever worked with.

Comment: I have to use the current beta3 version of Xcode. The stable version will crash if I try to open this file. Thanks for your help buddies!

Answer (score -1):

`Null` is not the same as `nil`.
A string that is `Null` is a non initialized string but a string nonetheless while in swift you have something that's called 'optional' that doesn't exist in obj-c.

so `String?` means that the function will return eaither a full fledged string or `nil` which is something undefined(not non-initialized).

> so in fact the closest thing in swift is `String!`" which is an
>   obligatory string(cannot return nil).

edit: As pointed out by Martin in the comments-the first part of the above mentioned statement is incorrect

Comment: Just for my understanding, why is this post voted down?

Comment: I would like to know as well

Comment: I did not vote, but the purpose of the _Nullable annotation is exactly that `NSString *` is mapped to Swift as `String?`, compare https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25.